# Localize plugin name

Tags: plugins, localization, l10n

Plugin name is a comment in WordPress. Since you can't write `php` code in the comments, is there a way to localize the plugin name and make it translatable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the full string of the plugin name into the plugin's text domain. WordPress looks this up automatically. Same with Description, PluginURI, Author and AuthorURI.

See the internal function [_get_plugin_data_markup_translate](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_get_plugin_data_markup_translate/).

The string extractor in Glotpress (and my own plugin Loco Translate) adds these header strings automatically to new POT files.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily.  You could copy all the files and change the plugin name.  But you still have to go through line by line.  Why not just use google-translate plugin on the page the plugin is displaying?   All languages are good then.

GTranslate works well for me.